# Django ForeignKey relationship is not working

Tags: python, django

There should be a table called like 'book_book_author(s)' due to the Foreign Key relationships. Otherwise I cannot access the Author.book_set.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Book(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    pub_date = models.DateField()

    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    language = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    print_length = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=0)

    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    authors=models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The database:

```
mysql> show tables;
+-------------------------------+
| Tables_in_eshop               |
+-------------------------------+
| account_user                  |
| account_user_groups           |
| account_user_user_permissions |
| auth_group                    |
| auth_group_permissions        |
| auth_permission               |
| book_author                   |
| book_book                     |
| django_admin_log              |
| django_content_type           |
| django_migrations             |
| django_session                |
+-------------------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: How do you query your author's book_set ?

Comment: What makes you think there should be a separate table? There definitely shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There should be a table called like 'book_book_author(s)

**No**: if you write a `ForeignKey` relation, then Django will add a *column* to your `book` table named `author_id`.

Now if you want to obtain the list of `Book`s for a given `Author`, Django will construct a query like:

```
SELECT book.*
FROM book
WHERE author_id = 123
```

with `123` the id of the `Author` you are querying. It does *not* construct such extra table. This would not be beneficial at all, since it would basically result in the *same* query (although on another table, and with a `JOIN`, which can make it *less* efficient).

To make it more efficient, Django will by default instruct the database will also construct an *index* on the `author_id` column, such that it can easily obtain the relevant `Book`s for an `Author` id. Usually this means that in *O(log n)*, or even *O(1)* one can get access to the list of books that are written by a given author. Depending on the database technology used, the index (or a large amount) will be stored in the database, and thus lookups will be quite fast.

You can thus see the `some_author.book_set` as a query you are going to execute, *not* a table.

> **Note**: for `ManyToManyField`s the situation is different, in that case it will construct an extra table. This is because usually, a column does not contain an arbitrary amount of values (well some databases can, but still it is inelegant design).

You can obtain the books of `some_author` with `some_author.book_set.all()`. Furthermore there is no `Author.book_set` (books that belong to at least one author). In this case this would mean simply *all* books, since every book belongs to an `Author`. If the `ForeignKey` was NULL-able, then we could filter like `Books.objects.filter(author__isnull=False)`.

Comment: oh yeah, I see. The ManyToMany Field works that way.

Answer (score 1):

Basically when you define a foreign key, then a new table is not created, rather the a reference of the corresponding row is made.

In your case you are creating a reference of *Author* on the *Book* table. Hence you can access all the books of an author by

```
Book.objects.filter(author__id = 'authorid')
```

Comment: Thanks. But what can I do to make it create a new table instead of a reference of the corresponding row is made?

Comment: Then you need to create a new table and make a many to many reference

Comment: @Jinx: assume we make a table, then how would that improve querying? It would only result in an extra `JOIN`, and thus less efficient queries.